# Multiple results from same click event in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get more then two results from the same click event. I would like to click on an event and see a result then click again and see the next result then click a third time and see a third result, etc. With the below code I can get two result but I can't seem to get additional results.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicked_once=false
  $(".card").click(function(){
    $("#q1").fadeIn();
    if (clicked_once) $('#q2').fadeIn();
    clicked_once=true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Boolean variables can only be 'true' or 'false', try to use an integer to count how many times user has clicked, and then do conditions on that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple math.

Keep `clicked_once  = -1` initially.

With every click, do it as :

```
clicked_once = (clicked_once+1)%3;
// 3 being the number of things that you want to pursue.
```

Later, check the value of clicked_once and perform the respective tasks.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need you can do something like this:

```
var clicks = [];

$('.card').click(function(event) {
    clicks.push(event);
    // here you can count the events collected to do something each time
    console.log('Clicks:', clicks.length);

    // or something specific
    if (clicks.length === 3) {
        console.log('Clicked three times', event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want some logic to increment a value so the next id is displayed. So each click would fadeIn one more element.

A simple case would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var clicked_once=false
var i = 0;

$(".card").click(function(evt){    
    i++;
    console.log("Clicked " + i + " times");
    $("#q"+ [i]).fadeIn();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Where each click event adds a +1 to the i variable, and that i variable is used in targeting the id you're trying to fadeIn.

The `evt.stopPropagation();` and `evt.preventDefault();` are included so the click event won't travel up the chain and fire again.

A quick jsFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/crztka73/4/

Of course this simple example only has 4 hard coded paragraphs, up to a q4 ID. After the 4th is reached, the i value will continue to get incremented, but without any more elements, no more items will fadeIn.